# What is g++-3 / gcc-3?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Trying to use make from cygwin using g++ I was getting Access Denied error messages.  Googling the error message I found a positing referring to g++-3 and gcc-3 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cygwin-g-3-exe-gcc-3-exe-corrupted-to-g-3-exe-dam-and-gcc-3-exe-dam-769722/)...

Changing the compiler to  g++-3 seems to fix the problem although I cannot find much information about both g++-3 and gcc-3.

Any ideas where I can find more information about them>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your point in the comment to Pete's answer, the `gcc` you type on the terminal is just a symlink to the actual gcc binary. It makes it easy to upgrade since you can just point the symlink to something else.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ ll /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-09-01 11:10 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.4*
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's version 3 of g++.  just like g++-4.1.2 would be version 4.1.2

Comment: And it would be a fairly old version of the compiler - the current release is (AFAIK) 4.5.1.  The very last 3.x release was 3.4.6 and that was made a year or more ago.

Comment: I would expect the newer version of g++ / gcc to maintain its name! This appears not to be the case since I have to call it explicitly as gcc-3....  Does anyone knows if the same applies for LINUX systems as well?

Comment: @JohnP: perhaps you have multiple versions of gcc installed? gcc-3 might be the one you have that works, and you may have another version that's giving you the access denied error. BTW/FWIW: yes, on Linux gcc can be invoked as either gcc or gcc-<version number>. If you have gcc-4.x you *can't* call it gcc-3. (On my system it's gcc-4.4.)